# Jquery: mark links as visited without opening them?

Tags: jquery, loops, hyperlink, browser-history, visited

I have no intention of just altering the link (I hear that's impossible, but if it's not I'd love to know how). I'm fine with adding it to the the browser history if that needs to be done.

I'd like to loop through all `<a>`'s on a page and change their state to visited. For example:

```
$("a").each(function(){
   //mark as visited (somehow?)
});
```

Essentially creating a "Mark All as Read" button on my page. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want your links to appear on the auto suggest drop down of the user's browser without actually visiting them? Do you want just the visual? Tell us what the result should be, there's a lot of good answers already but you know, we don't know which really answers the question!

Comment: I'm creating a chrome extension that's an rss reader. I count read articles vs un read articles by counting the links on a page. So to mark all as read I'd have to add them to the history somehow. Oh well... I may have to store the data in localStorage somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ...

1) Try using AJAX (ie. $.get(a.href)), but I don't know if that would actually work.

2) Try styling the links to look visited (by changing their CSS "color" attribute), although this approach won't actually make them in to visited links

3)  If neither of those work, you could try doing something like:

3A) Create a hidden IFRAME on the page

3B) Add a target attribute to every A tag on the page to make them point to the hidden IFRAME

3C) Invoke $("a").click() inside that each loop (possibly with a delay of some sort between each one to give the page time to load)

If none of those work, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: I was thinking about the $.get or $.load which i think added to the history - but that's since been fixed... i think.

Unfortunately I'm looking to actually change the state not just style. I've looked around and haven't found a way of adding to browser history... although a lot of people want that to happen.

Looks like the hidden iFrame is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a link that is visited (i.e. set its `href` to `window.location`), and set each of your target links' styles to that newly created link's computed style.

Comment: +1 Since this is the answer I was looking for when Google landed me on the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible in the way you want however you could copy the CSS attributes of a:visited to a new class called "visited" or whatever then apply them to the links you want.

```
$('a').addClass('visited');
```